# Can a Spout or Bolt access the ID by which it is known in the Topology?

Tags: apache-storm

Is there an API for a Storm Spout or Bolt to access its ID? The ID I am referring to is the `String` that was passed to the `setSpout` or `setBolt` method in class `backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder`.

It would be useful to access this string for the logging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getThisComponentId() on the passed topology context in the prepare method for bolts:

```
@Override
public void prepare(Map config, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;

    String componentId = context.getThisComponentId();
}
```

and in the open method for spouts.

There's also a more general method getComponentId(int taskId) that returns the component id for any given task.

Comment: I like the idea of getting the ID from the TopologyContext in the `prepare` or `open` method. Thanks. But I'm not sure how the `getComponentId` method could be used to solve the problem unless there is a way for a component to access its task ID.

Comment: There's a method on the TopologyContext that returns the component's task ID.  The getThisComponentId() method is just a convenience method for context.getComponentId(context.getThisTaskId())

Comment: In fact, you can find out just about anything you want to about the topology, including how the different component instances are deployed.

Comment: Yes, but the only opportunity a spout or a bolt has to get a reference to the TopologyContext is in the `open` or `prepare` method. So, unless I'm missing something, any solution to the problem involves code to be written there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The integer ID is given by `getThisTaskId()`.

For Spouts:

```
@Override
public void open(Map map, TopologyContext tc, SpoutOutputCollector soc) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\nThis Spout's ID is: "+context.getThisTaskId());
}
```

For Bolts:

```
@Override
public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext tc, OutputCollector oc) {
    this.boltId = tc.getThisTaskId();
}
```